# How to limit the amount of rows in a groupby by condition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Below are the first couple rows of a larger dataframe I am working with. I have code (thanks to user harvpan) to group all words together while speaker name doesn't change, keeping the 'start' value for the first word and the 'stop' value for the last word in the combination. This code:

```py
df.groupby([(df['speaker'] != df['speaker'].shift()).cumsum(), , df['speaker']], as_index=False).agg({
    'word': ' '.join,
    'start': 'min',
    'stop': 'max'
})
```

Turns this dataframe:

```
      word    start  stop      speaker
0       but   2.72  2.85        2
1    that's   2.85  3.09        2
2   alright   3.09  3.47        2
3     we'll   8.43  8.69        1
4      have   8.69  8.97        1
5        to   8.97  9.07        1
6      okay   9.19 10.01        2
7      sure  10.02 11.01        2
8     what?  11.02 12.00        1
```

Into this:

```
       word        start  stop speaker
0  but that's alright  2.72  3.47  2
1       we'll have to  8.43  9.07  1
2           okay sure  9.19 11.01  2
3               what? 11.02 12.00  1
```

Which is great. **However**, I want to limit the total number of words to be combined in each new word column. Specifically, I want the average number of words per new word combination to be around 4.

For example:

- if number of words before a speaker change <= 4, combine all words into 1 value
- if number of words before a speaker change > 4 AND # words // 4 == 0, combine words into combinations of 4 (ex. number of words before speaker change = 16, results in 4 groups)
- if number of words before a speaker change > 4 AND # words // 4 != 0, combine words into as many combinations of 4 as possible while allowing the remainder to be greater than 1. (ex. number of words before speaker change = 101. Instead of 25 groups of 4 and 1 group of 1, I want 24 groups of 4 and 1 group of 5).

So if I have this:

```
      word    start  stop      speaker
0       but   2.72  2.85        2
1    that's   2.85  3.09        2
2   alright   3.09  3.47        2
3     we'll   8.43  8.69        1
4      have   8.69  8.97        1
5        to   8.97  9.07        1
6      okay   9.19 10.01        2
7      sure  10.02 11.01        2
8     what?  11.02 12.00        1
9         i  12.01 13.00        2
10     want  13.01 14.00        2
11       to  14.01 15.00        2
12       go  15.01 16.00        2
13     there 16.01 17.00        2
14    where  17.01 18.00        1
15       is  18.01 19.00        1 
16       it  19.01 20.00        1         
17      you  20.01 21.00        1
18    would  21.01 22.00        1
19     like  22.01 23.00        1
20       to  23.01 24.00        1
21       go  24.01 25.00        1
```

I get this:

```
       word        start  stop speaker
0  but that's alright  2.72  3.47  2
1       we'll have to  8.43  9.07  1
2           okay sure  9.19 11.01  2
3               what? 11.02 12.00  1
4  I want to go there 12.01 17.00  2
5     where is it you 17.01 21.00  1
6    would like to go 21.01 25.00  1
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think I got it to work with this, taking your final code into account.  Just need to break down the "speaker" into partitions to group by.

Note that my example uses 2, instead of 4, words per speaker because it's easier to work with using your example data.

```
import pandas as pd
import math


z = pd.read_clipboard()

y = ((z.groupby((z['speaker'] != z['speaker'].shift(1)).cumsum()).cumcount().apply(float)+1) / 2)

z['speaker2'] = z['speaker'].apply(str) + y.apply(math.floor).apply(str)

z.groupby([(z['speaker2'] != z['speaker2'].shift()).cumsum(),  z['speaker2']], as_index=False).agg({
    'word': ' '.join,
    'start': 'min',
    'stop': 'max'

         word  start   stop
0  but that's   2.72   3.09
1     alright   3.09   3.47
2  we'll have   8.43   8.97
3          to   8.97   9.07
4   okay sure   9.19  11.01
5       what?  11.02  12.00
})
```